# How to host my local ckan instance on the web?

Tags: ckan

Hey I installed ckan(latest version) from source on my local machine. Its running fine on my local server. I want to make my ckan instance go live. Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The steps you made to make it run locally, you have to replicate those but on a live server. If you want to serve the very same CKAN instance from your local machine in production i would advise strongly against it. Ideally you would have some Ubuntu 14.04 server hosted somewhere on which you can setup everything using the CKAN package or source installation.

Comment: Why would you advise against serving it from my local machine? I just wanted to do some basic level testing before I can host it from a proper ubuntu server.

Comment: You just said you wanted it to go "live". What is your definition of live then?

Comment: Yeah I mean I want to setup the postgresql on my local machine and then host the instance on the web at any address. Basically I want to serve the instance from my pc on an address which is on the web e.g exampleckan.tk. So when anyone opens exampleckan.tk from their computer they access the ckan instance I have setup. Im sorry Im new to web hosting. I would be thankful if you can please help.